# How to break when a specific exception type is thrown in GDB?

Tags: c++, gdb

According to the documentation I can break on specific exception type by using conditional breakpoints. However the syntax for the condition isn't very clear to me:

```
condition bnum <expression>
```

Looking at the expression syntax I think this is the pattern I need:

> `{type} addr`

However, I don't know what I should pass for the `addr` argument. I tried the following:

```
(gdb) catch throw
(gdb) condition 1 boost::bad_function_call *
```

But it doesn't work (gdb breaks on all exception types).

Can anyone help?

---

#### Update

I also tried @Adam's suggestion, but it results in an error message:

```
(gdb) catch throw boost::bad_function_call
Junk at end of arguments.
```

Without `boost::` namespace:

```
(gdb) catch throw bad_function_call
Junk at end of arguments.
```

---

#### Workaround

Breaking in the constructor of `bad_function_call` works.

Comment: How about setting up a breakpoint on the constructor of the Exception object?

Answer (score 29):

**EDIT**

The documentation suggests that `catch throw <exceptname>` can be used to break whenever an exception of type `<exceptname>` is thrown; however, that doesn't seem to work in practice.

```
(gdb) help catch
Set catchpoints to catch events.
Raised signals may be caught:
        catch signal              - all signals
        catch signal <signame>    - a particular signal
Raised exceptions may be caught:
        catch throw               - all exceptions, when thrown
        catch throw <exceptname>  - a particular exception, when thrown
        catch catch               - all exceptions, when caught
        catch catch <exceptname>  - a particular exception, when caught
Thread or process events may be caught:
        catch thread_start        - any threads, just after creation
        catch thread_exit         - any threads, just before expiration
        catch thread_join         - any threads, just after joins
Process events may be caught:
        catch start               - any processes, just after creation
        catch exit                - any processes, just before expiration
        catch fork                - calls to fork()
        catch vfork               - calls to vfork()
        catch exec                - calls to exec()
Dynamically-linked library events may be caught:
        catch load                - loads of any library
        catch load <libname>      - loads of a particular library
        catch unload              - unloads of any library
        catch unload <libname>    - unloads of a particular library
The act of your program's execution stopping may also be caught:
        catch stop

C++ exceptions may be caught:
        catch throw               - all exceptions, when thrown
        catch catch               - all exceptions, when caught
Ada exceptions may be caught:
        catch exception           - all exceptions, when raised
        catch exception <name>    - a particular exception, when raised
        catch exception unhandled - all unhandled exceptions, when raised
        catch assert              - all failed assertions, when raised

Do "help set follow-fork-mode" for info on debugging your program
after a fork or vfork is caught.

Do "help breakpoints" for info on other commands dealing with breakpoints.
```

Comment: See here too: Setting Catchpoints (http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Catchpoints.html)

Comment: Using `catch throw <exceptname>` results in the error message "Junk at end of arguments."

Comment: @StackedCrooked: Oops, you're right.  That's what I get for looking at the docs without actually trying it.

Comment: The documentation actually says that C++ exceptions cannot be specified; by omission of `catch exception <exceptionname>` under the heading for C++. As another example, according to the documentation you posted, catching unhandled exceptions when they are raised is only supported for Ada.

Answer (score 20):

When gdb command 'catch throw' fails, try this workaround :
(tested with Linux g++ 4.4.5/gdb 6.6)
1/ Add this code anywhere in the program to debug :

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <exception>
#include <typeinfo>

struct __cxa_exception {
    std::type_info *inf;
};
struct __cxa_eh_globals {
    __cxa_exception *exc;
};
extern "C" __cxa_eh_globals* __cxa_get_globals();
const char* what_exc() {
    __cxa_eh_globals* eh = __cxa_get_globals();
    if (eh && eh->exc && eh->exc->inf)
        return eh->exc->inf->name();
    return NULL;
}
```

2/ In gdb you will then be able to filter exceptions with :

```
(gdb) break __cxa_begin_catch  
(gdb) cond N (what_exc()?strstr(what_exc(),"exception_name"):0!=0)
```

where N is the breakpoint number, and exception_name is the name of exception for which we wish to break.

Answer (score 15):

From what I have understood from the question here, you want to break when a specific exception `boost::bad_function_call` is thrown in your application.

```
$> gdb /path/to/binary
(gdb) break boost::bad_function_call::bad_function_call()
(gdb) run --some-cli-options
```

So when the temporary object `boost::bad_function_call` is constructed in preparation for the `throw`; gdb will break out!

I have tested this and it does work. If you precisely know the way the exception object is being constructed then you can set breakpoint on the specific constructor, otherwise as shown in the example below, you can omit the arguments prototype list, and `gdb` will set break points on all different flavours of the constructor.

```
$ gdb /path/to/binary

(gdb) break boost::bad_function_call::bad_function_call
Breakpoint 1 at 0x850f7bf: boost::bad_function_call::bad_function_call. (4 locations)

(gdb) info breakpoints
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address    What
1       breakpoint     keep y   <MULTIPLE>
1.1                         y     0x0850f7bf in boost::bad_function_call::bad_function_call() at /usr/include/boost/function/function_base.hpp:742
1.2                         y     0x0850fdd5 in boost::bad_function_call::bad_function_call(boost::bad_function_call const&) at /usr/include/boost/function/function_base.hpp:739
1.3                         y     0x0863b7d2 <boost::bad_function_call::bad_function_call()+4>
1.4                         y     0x086490ee <boost::bad_function_call::bad_function_call(boost::bad_function_call const&)+6>
```

Comment: This works really well. Thanks for the nice and easy workaround.

Comment: To set breakpoints on all constructors of an exception you can use the regex-break command, e.g.: `rb my_exception::my_exception` - btw, does the `break boost::bad_function_call()` command really works for you? I have to use `break boost::bad_function_call::bad_function_call()` with gdb 7.8.2. Otherwise it says: 'Function "boost::bad_function_call()" not defined.'

Comment: I wonder if this would also work for `std::exception`, for when you want to ignore all other thrown exceptions that don't derive from `std::exception`.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is to rely on the `tinfo` argument available when the catch point is triggered, which is a pointer to the object returned by `typeid(type)`.

So say if I want to catch exception `std::bad_alloc` being thrown, I could just do:

```
> p &typeid(std::bad_alloc)
> $1 = (__cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info *) 0x8c6db60 <typeinfo for std::bad_alloc>
> catch throw if tinfo == 0x8c6db60
```

Comment: How do you get &typeid(std::bad_alloc) to work in gdb? Mine just says `No symbol "typeid" in current context.`

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume you have the following code.cpp with a thread that throws an exception:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void thr()
{
    while (true) {
      new int[1000000000000ul];
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std::thread t(thr);
  t.join();
  std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Compile it with using the following CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(tutorial)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(test_exceptions main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(test stdc++ pthread)
```

Now you can play with, running it will give you an abort because of bad_alloc.
Before going on, it's better if you install libstd debug symbols, `sudo apt-get install libstdc++6-5-dbg` or whatever version you have.

## Debug compilation

If you are compiling in `Debug` you can follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12434170/5639395 because constructors are usually defined.

## Release compilation

If you are compiling in `DebWithRelInfo` you may not be able to find a proper constructor where to put your breakpoint because of the compiler optimization. In this case, you have some other options. Let's continue.

### Source code change solution

If you can change the source code easily, this will work https://stackoverflow.com/a/9363680/5639395

### Gdb catch throw easy solution

If you don't want to change the code, you can try to see if `catch throw bad_alloc` or in general `catch throw exception_name` works.

### Gdb catch throw workaround

I will build on top of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6849989/5639395
We will add a breakpoint in gdb in the function `__cxxabiv1::__cxa_throw` . This function takes a parameter called `tinfo` that has the information we need to conditionally check for the exception we care about.

We want something like *catch throw if exception==bad_alloc*, so how to find the proper comparison?
It turns out that `tinfo` is a pointer to a structure that has a variable called `__name` inside. This variable has a string with the mangled name of the exception type.

So we can do something like: *catch throw if tinfo->__name == mangled_exception_name*

We are almost there!

We need a way to do string comparison, and it turns out gdb has a built-in function $_streq(str1,str2) that does exactly what we need.
The mangled name of the exception is a little harder to find, but you can try to guess it or check the Appendix of this answer. Let's assume for now it is "St9bad_alloc".

The final instruction is:

`catch throw if $_streq(tinfo->__name ,  "St9bad_alloc")`

or equivalent

`break __cxxabiv1::__cxa_throw if $_streq(tinfo->__name ,  "St9bad_alloc")`

## How to find the name of your exception

You have two options

### Look for the symbol in the library

Assuming that you installed the libstd debug symbols, you can find the library name like this:

`apt search libstd | grep dbg | grep installed`

The name is something like this `libstdc++6-5-dbg`

Now check the files installed:

`dpkg -L libstdc++6-5-dbg`

Look for something that has a debug in the path, and a .so extension. In my pc I have `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/debug/libstdc++.so.6.0.21`.
Finally, look for the exception you want in there.

`nm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/debug/libstdc++.so.6.0.21 | grep -i bad_alloc`

Or 
`nm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/debug/libstdc++.so.6.0.21 | grep -i runtime_error`
etc.

In my case I found something like `00000000003a4b20 V _ZTISt9bad_alloc` which suggested me to use "St9bad_alloc" as the name.

### Throw it in gdb and inspect the name in there

This is easy, just start gdb, `catch throw` everything and run the small executable I wrote before. When you are inside gdb, you can issue a `p *tinfo` and look for the `__name` description from gdb.

`gdb -ex 'file test_exceptions' -ex 'catch throw' -ex 'run'`

`(gdb) p *tinfo
$1 = {_vptr.type_info = 0x406260 <vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info+16>, 
  __name = 0x7ffff7b8ae78 <typeinfo name for std::bad_alloc> "St9bad_alloc"}`

Answer (score 2):

As others already mentioned this functionality doesn't work in practice. But as workaround you can put condition on `catch throw`. When exception is thrown we come to `__cxa_throw` function. It has several parameters pointing to exception class, so we can set condition on one of them. In the sample gdb session below, I put condition on `dest` parameter of `__cxa_throw`. The only problem is that value of `dest` (0x80486ec in this case) is unknown in advance. It can be known, for example, by first running gdb without condition on breakpoint.

```
[root@localhost ~]#
[root@localhost ~]# gdb ./a.out
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.2
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i686-pc-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /root/a.out...done.
(gdb) catch throw
Catchpoint 1 (throw)
(gdb) condition 1 dest==0x80486ec
No symbol "dest" in current context.
(gdb) r
warning: failed to reevaluate condition for breakpoint 1: No symbol "dest" in current context.
warning: failed to reevaluate condition for breakpoint 1: No symbol "dest" in current context.
warning: failed to reevaluate condition for breakpoint 1: No symbol "dest" in current context.
Catchpoint 1 (exception thrown), __cxxabiv1::__cxa_throw (obj=0x804a080, tinfo=0x8049ca0, dest=0x80486ec <_ZNSt13runtime_errorD1Ev@plt>) at ../../../../gcc-4.4.3/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_throw.cc:68
68      ../../../../gcc-4.4.3/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_throw.cc: No such file or directory.
        in ../../../../gcc-4.4.3/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_throw.cc
(gdb) bt
#0  __cxxabiv1::__cxa_throw (obj=0x804a080, tinfo=0x8049ca0, dest=0x80486ec <_ZNSt13runtime_errorD1Ev@plt>) at ../../../../gcc-4.4.3/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_throw.cc:68
#1  0x08048940 in main () at test.cpp:14
(gdb) i b
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address    What
1       breakpoint     keep y   0x008d9ddb exception throw
        stop only if dest==0x80486ec
        breakpoint already hit 1 time
(gdb)
```

**Update**

You must also load debug info for libstdc++ for this workaround to work.

Comment: On my system (Linux, g++ 4.5.2) __cxa_throw does not seem to have any parameters ;-( At least gdb shows it as __cxa_throw() when I break on that function.

How do you compile your program?

Comment: My system is Fedora 12, gcc version 4.4.4 20100630. I compile this way `g++ -g test.cpp`.

Comment: I have also installed and loaded debug info for libstdc++. On Fedora this is done by command `debuginfo-install libstdc++`. I think this is the reason why you dont see parameters of `__cxa_throw`. Check for debug info for libstdc++ in your system.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is a recent fix, but with GDB `GNU gdb (Debian 9.1-2) 9.1`, I have used `catch throw std::logical_error` successfully. I would hate to generalise prematurely, but it is possible this now works correctly in GDB (April 2020).

Answer (score 1):

I think I can answer the part about setting conditional breaks. I won't answer question regarding exceptions as __raise_exception seems to not exist in g++ 4.5.2 (?)

Let's assume that you have following code (I use void to get something similar to __raise_exception from gdb doc)

```
void foo(void* x) {

}

int main() {
    foo((void*)1);
    foo((void*)2);
}
```

to break at foo(2) you use following commands

```
(gdb) break foo
Breakpoint 1 at 0x804851c: file q.cpp, line 20.
(gdb) condition 1 x == 2
```

If you run with

```
(gdb) r
```

you will see that it stops on the second foo call, but not on the first one

I think, what they meant in docs is that you set break on function __raise_exception (very implementation dependent)

```
 /* addr is where the exception identifier is stored
    id is the exception identifier.  */
    void __raise_exception (void **addr, void *id);
```

and then set conditional break on id as described above (you have to somehow determine what is id for yours exception type).

Unfortunately

```
 (gdb) break __raise_exception
```

results with (g++ 4.5.2)

```
 Function "__raise_exception" not defined.
```

Comment: It seems like the function name in g++ 4.5.2's standard library is `__cxa_raise`.  Setting a breakpoint there seems to be equivalent to just saying `catch throw`.

Comment: @Adam I can't break at __cxa_raise (Function "__cxa_raise" not defined) There are functions __cxa_allocate_exception and __cxa_throw though. 

The problem is that both these functions are defined with no parameters and thus there is no way to do a conditional break on type of the exception.

I did some research on the internet and it seems that there has been a bug in gdb docs for quite long time. I verified with 'nm' command that executable does not contain __raise_exception symbol. Not sure about the bug though.

Comment: @mmilewski: Oops yes, I meant `__cxa_throw`, not `__cxa_raise` (another failure on my part).  You could still create a conditional breakpoint that looked at the stack/registers to determine the type of exception, but that's pretty kludgy and platform-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

In case the problem is that there is no valid stack trace (not breaking in raise), it seems to be a problem when re-compiling without re-starting gdb. 
( i.e. calling "make" inside the gdb console).

After having re-started gdb, it breaks correctly in raise.c 
(my versions : GNU gdb 8.1.0.20180409-git, gcc 7.4.0,  GNU make 4.1)