# Find Source of STL::Exception in basic_string

Tags: c++, linux, string, exception, std

I am trying to track the source of a std::exception, in basic_string::erase, I wrapped all the locations where I am calling erase directly in try/catch and am not seeing any of these catch blocks be hit, so it must be being called internally from another basic_string method. The exception appears to be the result of a race condition in the code i am working with, so it is very difficult to reproduce, any thoughts on how I could detect and or get a stack trace from this exception? btw this is c++ code on an x86 linux box.

Thank you

Comment: If `basic_string::erase` is throwing an exception due to a race condition, I fail to see why you need the source of the exception.  Remove the race condition.

Comment: The standard says that `basic_string::erase` throws: out_of_range if pos > size().

Comment: Are you using an erase call in a race condition?

Comment: @MooingDuck: Presumably the OP doesn't know what the race condition *is*, only that there seems to be one, and (s)he hopes that tracking down the location of the exception will help identify it. (See [*De dicto* and *de re* on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_dicto_and_de_re).)

Comment: Are you positive that it's an exception, and not an assertion?

Comment: @ildjarn : yes i am positive it was an exception

Comment: @ruakh correctomundo! Thank you all for your help, the answer below actually helped me solve this problem I was able to use breaking on all thows in conjunction with gdb breakpoint functions to capture why this was happening and then resolve it.

Comment: @Mooing Duck thank you for the obvious suggestion, but with out finding the source of the exception I didn't know what was involved in the race condition that was causing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try

(gdb) catch throw

Then gdb will trigger breakpoint each time exception is thrown. You'll see a callstack.

EDIT: This post is a good bunch of tricks for debugging exceptions: [GDB: How to break when a specific exception type is thrown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835728/gdb-how-to-break-when-a-specific-exception-type-is-thrown)