# gdb "Junk at end of arguments." when trying "catch throw std::bad_aloc"

Tags: c++, exception, gdb, bad-alloc

I've been trying to debug an instance of std::bad_alloc in gdb.

In gdb 7.4.1 and 7.5.91 I tried

```
(gdb) catch throw std::bad_alloc
Junk at end of arguments.
```

I've tried wrapping std::bad_alloc in single and double quotes, without success.

Is there a workaround for this, or another way to catch bad_alloc?

Edit: Just to say I tried the suggestion from [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835728/gdb-how-to-break-when-a-specific-exception-type-is-thrown) to break on the constructor of bad_alloc by doing

```
(gdb) b 'std::bad_alloc::bad_alloc()'
```

but this breakpoint was not found.

Comment: That question doesn't address the "Junk at end of arguments" issue. I've edited my question to mention that I attempted the solution from that question.

Comment: Yes, it does, as do several of the answers.