# Specify a particular exception to stop GDB using catch

Tags: c++, debugging, exception, gdb

`catch throw` tells GDB to stop when an exception occurs. This has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115428/run-an-application-in-gdb-until-an-exception-occurs).

However, I define a few exception types in my program, I need a way to tell GDB to only stop when one of my exceptions is thrown. Is there a way to do this? I know Visual Studio lets you specify an exception to force the debugger to stop. How do I do this in GDB?

Comment: Have you tried reading the GDB documentation to find an answer? What did you find? Why didn't it help you?  Or do you expect *us* to read the documentation *for you* and just spoon-feed you the answer? If so; sorry, that's not how it works.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/6835728/72178

Comment: @ks1322 Ah, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the exception is defined in my own program, the correct way to do this is to simply put a breakpoint in the constructor of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

GDB cannot do this. If you have some other debugger, it can help you here.